# Django database - how to add this column in raw SQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Suppose I have my models set up already.

```
class books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField...
    ISBN = models.Integer...
```

What if I want to add this column to my table?

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

How would I write the raw SQL in my database so that this column works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should investigate a tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org), which does all this for you.

However the SQL would be something like (assuming you're using MySQL):

```
ALTER TABLE `appname_books` ADD COLUMN `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE;
ALTER TABLE `appname_books` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES auth_user (`id`);
```

Comment: If I already have running data, and a set-up database....can I use South right now? Or will I have to re-create all the tables?

Comment: Anyone who comes along and sees alex's comment, this is addressed in his later question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445761/django-migrations-is-it-possible-to-use-south-in-the-middle-of-the-project).

Comment: @TIMEX, yes. You can start using South at any time.