# Django migrations--is it possible to use South in the middle of the project?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-south

I already started a project, and the models are all synced and everything.

Comment: how did you implement this? I'm using mysql and getting problems when I try to `$ python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I think it is not too late. I've moved to south in a middle of a project and I am happy with that choice. I think it is a big help for deployment.

The initialization of the south app can be done at any moment.

Answer (score 4):

It's even mentioned in docs:

http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/QuickStartGuide#a1.SetupeveryapplicationtobetrackablebySouth

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straight forward to start using South.

Just follow the [installation instructions](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/installation.html) (don't forget to run syncdb at the end).

Then you can [convert the app to south](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html):

```
./manage.py convert_to_south myapp
```

Then you can make modifications to your model and do [schemamigrations](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#schemamigration) or even do [datamigrations](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#datamigration).