# OperationalError: No Such Column after adding to models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-userena

I'm using userena, and I added a single line to add zipcodes to the models.py in my app folder.  I now get

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signup/

no such column: accounts_myprofile.zipcode
```

Anytime I try to signup.  In an effort to try to fix this, I deleted by sqlite3.db and then ran a syncdb and flush (without any errors), thinking this was rebuild the db, but I don't see any sqlite3.db in my project folder.

My question is, is this a problem related to userena and how do I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to use migration here

Comment: this is django 1.6, can i use migrate?  Someone also suggest I use south, but can I install south now and run migration?  Or is this something that would only help me if I were to have set it up from the beginning?

Comment: sure do. you have to use south ( south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: you can check this SO post for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445761/django-migrations-is-it-possible-to-use-south-in-the-middle-of-the-project :)